# Auto-generate code based on database table definition?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mysql

Is it possible to automatically generate a simple form, using c# or javascript in asp.net, from a given database table definition? To give you an example table `testTable` has columns `userFirstName, userLastName, userAddress, userEmail` and I want to take this definition and make a form that has a label and textbox for each of these columns of the table? How would I even start to do this if it's possible. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well asp.net MVC scaffolding is your best tool then

Check out this article for tutorial:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

Answer (score 0):

For pay:
[ASPRunner.NET](http://xlinesoft.com/asprunnernet/)

For free:
I would recommend using Entity Framework to generate domain objects from your database and then you could use those domain objects as model classes in ASP.NET MVC, which provides for UI scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer an open-source utility https://github.com/wsq003/DapperHelper 
It can generate C# classes and CRUD SQL scripts from database tables.